# Execute a function in VB.NET without first declaring an instance of the class

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way for me to make a function call on a new instance of a variable without first declaring it?

So for example in Java you could do:

```
new foo().bar(parameters);
```

I've tried something similar in Visual Basic, but it's a syntax error. For the moment I'm creating a variable and then running the function.

```
dim instance as new foo()
instance.bar(parameters)
```

Is there something I can do similarly to the Java code above?

Comment: Looks like you need to look into `Shared` methods in instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly.  You can do so in a larger expression by surrounding the instantiation in parenthesis, for instance:

```
MessageBox.Show((New String("y"c, 1)).ToUpper())
```

Or, in fact, while I find it more confusing, you don't actually even need the parenthesis around the instantiation:

```
MessageBox.Show(New String("y"c, 1).ToUpper())
```

However, if you want to just call a method like that, the only way I know of is to wrap in in a `CType` operator.  For instance, if you had a class like this:

```
Private Class Test
    Public Sub Show()
        MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    End Sub
End Class
```

You could call the `Show` method like this:

```
CType(New Test(), Test).Show()
```

But, it is a bit clumsy.

Actually, SSS provided an even better answer since I posted this yesterday.  Instead of wrapping it in a `CType` operator, you can use the `Call` keyword.  For instance:

```
Call New Test().Show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, I use the following pattern often. The alternative is to add parameters to Sub New(). I use this pattern when initialisation can fail, and you want to return a null reference (Nothing) instead of throwing an exception.

```
Public Class Foo
  Property Prop1 As String
  Property Prop2 As String

  Public Shared Function Bar(p1 As String, p2 As String) As Foo
    Dim f As Foo
    If p1 = "" Or p2 = "" Then
      'validation check - if either parameter is an empty string, initialisation fails and we return a null reference
      f = Nothing
    Else
      'parameters are valid
      f = New Foo
      f.Prop1 = p1
      f.Prop2 = p2
    End If
    Return f
  End Function

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Optional - marking the Sub New as "Private" forces the caller to use the Bar() function to instantiate
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <remarks></remarks>
  Private Sub New()

  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Like SSS has provided the way which is best for Classes, another way around could be of using Modules if it is not a compulsion for you to use Classes only.

Modules provide easy access for function without even creating objects for them.